# How do I enable continuous scrolling in the Nook app?

Tags: nook, nook-for-android

Is there a way to enable continuous scrolling on the Nook app for Android? The Kindle app allowed me to read by scrolling vertically, but I can't find a similar option in the Nook app.

Comment: I don't use the Nook app so I don't know, but if there is no option to scroll vertically, then it needs the developer of the app to implement that feature first.